# Getting details from database Spring Boot , Exception error

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to get data by multiple data from database on the basis of multiple Ids using Spring boot.
Basically it is a GET call which takes request parameters as a list of IDs and return response accordingly. IDs are unique in database

```
 Url : api/details/1a,2a,3b
```

I am getting response as:

```
Get(value = "api/details/{Ids})
{
[id="1a",name="Raj", interest="Football"],
[id="2a",name="Tom", interest="Cricket"]
[id="3b",name="Kane", interest="Baseball"]

}
```

It is fine. But when i am giving a wrong Id, I am getting response as:

```
Url : api/details/xyz,abc,3b
{
null,
null,
[id="3b",name="Kane", interest="Baseball"]

}
```

I am expecting that instead of null it show say that the ID is not present along with Status code. Something like

```
{
2-Not found,3-Not Found, 
id="3b",name="Kane", hobby="Baseball, 
}
```

My controller class is like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/details{Ids}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<Game>> 
getMultipleDetails(@PathVariable("Idss") String Idss) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    List<String> ids = Arrays.asList(Idss.split(","));
    List<Game> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Game details= null;
    for (String id : ids) {

        details= da.getMultipleDetails(id);
        list.add(devices);
    }
    if (details== null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.toString());
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Game>>(list, headers, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

}

My repository class is like:

```
public Device getMultipleDetails(String id) {
    Game details= null;
    try {
        details= jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Id = ?",new DeviceRowMapper(), id);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log the system generated Id
        String systemRefId = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        LOGGER.error(systemRefId, e);
        //throw new DatabaseException(systemRefId, e);
    }
    return details;

}
```

Game is my model class that conatins id, name, hobby

Comment: What is the exception/error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're setting the `ResponseEntity<List<Game>>` you should only return a `List` with `Game` objects inside.

Not sure why you want to return the failed ones in the same List but as a workaround I will set `id` of the not found and, in the fields `name` and `Game` I will set 'Not found' instead of returning null objects. For example:

```
public Device getMultipleDetails(String id) {
    Game details = new Game();
    try {
        details= jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Id = ?",new DeviceRowMapper(), id);
    //If details is not null but it's empty
    if (StringUtils.IsEmpty(details.getId())) {
      details.setId(id);
      details.setName("Not Found");
      details.setGame("Not Found");
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log the system generated Id
        String systemRefId = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
        LOGGER.error(systemRefId, e);
        //If details is null it will trow null pointer exception
        details = new Game();
        details.setId(id);
        details.setName("Not Found");
        details.setGame("Not Found");
    }

    return details;

}
```

I strongly recommend you to rename the field Game in you Game class. **A field should not duplicate the name of its containing class.**

It's confusing to have a class member with the same name (case differences aside) as its enclosing class. This is particularly so when you consider the common practice of naming a class instance for the class itself.

Best practice dictates that any field or member with the same name as the enclosing class be renamed to be more descriptive of the particular aspect of the class it represents or holds.

I would recommend to rename it to something like `typeOfGame` for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot @juanlumn. But still i am getting error. I have made the required changes. It is showingjava.lang.NullPointerException: null                                                 { if (null == device ||   null==device.getDeviceId()) {
            device.setDeviceId(id); --here
            device.setDeviceName("Not Found");                                                            
 }  DO I have to make changes in controller class as well

Comment: I've edited the answer, first I've changed the `Game details = null` by `Game details = new Game();` second I've added `StringUtils.IsEmpty` in the if statement

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you are adding in a null object.         if (null == details || null == details.getId()) {
      details.setId(id);
      details.setName("Not Found");
      details.setGame("Not Found");
    }

Answer (score 0):

You should manage the empty objects, and manage the message also, the code should be like this, because if not, only the **last detail** is the one evaluated, thats why the exception is not raised.

```
for (String id : ids) {

    details= da.getMultipleDetails(id);
    list.add(devices);
    if (details== null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.toString());
    }
}
```